# List of mso- attributes

Tags: css, ms-office

I'm searching for a list of Microsoft specific CSS attributes with mso- prefix.

Any link to an offical or unofficial source would be awesome.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I just had the same difficulties to find a list of MS Office prefixed style properties. I found this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa155477), but it was not even well organized. 
So I decided to write down a list in a Gist for everyone are looking for having these troubles as well. Still not found all things, but you may find this source helpful at least as a reference on the web.

**MS Office prefixed Style properties**
https://gist.github.com/webtobesocial/ac9d052595b406d5a5c1

Comment: Link now appears to be at https://gist.github.com/p3t3r67x0/ac9d052595b406d5a5c1

Answer (score 13):

Microsoft’s information on the topic can be found via the page [Microsoft® Office HTML and XML Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa155477). It links to an .exe file, which when executed (on Windows, of course) installs C:\ofhtml9\ofhtml9.chm. The material is rather extensive and not particularly well organized. But search for “mso-” in the Search box, and you’ll find a long table titled “Style Attributes” and containing both standard and nonstandard CSS properties.

The table “shows the style attributes used by Microsoft Office 2000”, but I’m not aware of similar information for other Office versions.

Comment: all links are down... :(

Answer (score 9):

This [MSO - Style Reference Sheet](https://stigmortenmyre.no/mso/html/concepts/ofconstyletable.htm) link has a list of 372 Microsoft specific styles which includes common ones used in email e.g. `style="mso-line-height-rule:exactly;"` which prevents outlook from overwriting your line-height style `line-height:20px;`etc. All you have to do with the link is type `mso` into the filter bar and it should give you the list of Microsoft specific CSS attributes with mso- prefix.

Answer (score 4):

Best list I've seen of the attributes is located at [Litmus](https://litmus.com/community/learning/8-outlook-overview).

The real issue isn't finding a list of mso- attributes though, it's the details as to how they work.

For anyone following in my footsteps you will probably have issues opening the CHM file linked by others on this thread. There is a CHM reader for the Mac that works pretty well, though it's pointless as there is hardly any useful information contained within. You can find that reader on the [App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/chm-reader/id424182884?mt=12)

Answer (score 3):

The closest i can find is this list:
<del>[Link to list](http://devfiles.myopera.com/articles/599/cssproplist-url.htm)</del> [Archive of Link to list](http://web.archive.org/web/20111227154247/http://devfiles.myopera.com/articles/599/cssproplist-url.htm)

I assume that a ctrl+f on mso, will quickly show you all you need? Then from there you can quickly gather your list.

Comment: Thanks, thats enough for me. Maybe a list with accepted parameters as addition

Comment: This link no longer works, can't find a backup/alternative of it either.

Comment: @notacouch or anyone else that wants the link mentioned above-- using archive.org I found it, see: http://web.archive.org/web/20111227154247/http://devfiles.myopera.com/articles/599/cssproplist-url.htm